# EF (Table per Type) - Change Entity's class type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first, table-per-type

I'm using EF 6.1 in Web API app. I'm implementing Table per Type (TPT). I followed [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) tutorial and everything works fine. I want to change the type of entity when updating the entity.

```
public abstract class BillingDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("BankAccounts")]
public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{ }

[Table("CreditCards")]
public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{ }
```

I have CreditCard type entity already saved. When updating the entity, I want to save it as BankAccount type with the same primary key. Is it possible?

This is what I tried, But it throws **DbUpdateConcurrencyException**.

```
BankAccount record = ...;
record.Id = 1;  //the Id of CreditCard entity

ctx.BillingDetail.Attach(record);
ctx.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is ctx.News - BankAccounts? Can you paste more code. I can not get it from the sample. Otherwise the objects are database records - writing record in table B by getting info from a record from table A is ok.

Comment: Changing an Entity's type is always a very strange and doubtful action. Don't expect EF to be any different. This really is an indication of a fault in your business logic. Much better to fix that so that you don't even want this.

Comment: Yes @HenkHolterman It is not a good practice in OO world. I'm implementing this as a business requirement.

Comment: This is a low level technical implementation issue, it can't be a business req. And in the accounting world, line items never change identity or value.

Comment: I used types in the tutorial so that it is easy for you all to get the idea. In my app, I'm trying to keep draft(tempory) data in one table and published(final) data in the other. My plan was to move the drafted one's data to the published table while keeping the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

> "When updating the entity, I want to save it as BankAccount type with
>   the same primary key. Is it possible?"

If the primary key is database generated - no, because these are two separate tables in SQL and if their respected primary keys ( named Id ) are set to be database generated by incrementing the id you are violating the rule of the generation. Read the message of the exception and the message of the inner exception too - maybe there is the explanation.

Check the convention of EF for properties named Id which are int and are labeled as Key.

From [Entity Framework Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx).

> Code First infers that a property is a primary key if a property on a class is named “ID” (not case sensitive), or the class name followed by "ID". If the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID it will be configured as an identity column.

Check the table schema of the SQL in order to verify this. I am almost sure the Id columns is set to be database generated by incrementation of the Id.

Comment: I'm implementing TPT here. so there are 3 tables for each type(BillingDetail, BankAccount and CreditCard). The primary key Id resides in BillingDetail table.

Comment: And when you try to change an Id you are (1) overriding another existing Id or (2) trying to skip some Ids. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to keep the same primary key for the entity. If you think this in DB side you will get the idea. In BillingDatail table the record will stay as it is. I want to remove the record from BankAccount table and add it to CreditCard table. This is totally doable in DB side. The problem is with EF. EF track it as a BankAccount type entity. So I can't change the type to CreditCard.